# Laravel migrations change default value of column

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have a table with a default value already assigned. For an example we can look at the following:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('active')->default(1);
        });
```

I now want to change my default value on the active field. I am expecting to do something like this:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'active')) {
                $table->integer('active')->default(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

But of course it tells me the column is already there. How can I simply update the default value of column x without dropping the column?

Comment: well since its only about one column you can do it manually by using interface like phpmyadmin(xampp), workbench etc. so you will not loose any data..

Comment: Thats what I have done for now to fix it on our live server but I would still like to know whats the best way moving forward.  Otherwise I was also thinking of just upgrading to laravel 5

Comment: here is a link that might help you - http://www.flipflops.org/2013/05/25/modify-an-existing-database-column-in-a-laravel-migration/

Comment: Seems like a raw query inside my migration script is the way to go here. Really thought I was missing something obvious here.

Comment: yes it could work both the ways - by writing the alter query inside existing migration or inside a newly created migration..

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use [`change()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns) method:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('active')->default(0)->change();
});
```

Then run `migrate` command.

**Update**

For Laravel 4 use something like this:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE COLUMN `active` `active` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;');
```

Inside `up()` method instead of `Schema::table();` clause.

Comment: Sorry did not add but I'm using laravel 4.2

Comment: For Laravel 4 you should use raw query. Please check updated question.

Comment: do you know how to rollback?

Comment: To remove a default value from a column, use default(NULL)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: Hi, I've used your code to change DB column using new migration, migrate successfully but no change in DB columns! Any idea what was the issue? thanks.

Comment: Note if there's `enum` column on that table then `change()` is not supported, the way to go is `DB::statement...`

Comment: @rüff0 `$table->integer('active')->default(1)->change();`

Comment: How can I change string to int and add default value? I tried this but PostgreSQL throws `cast error. $table->integer('score')->default(0)->change();`

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the [change function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns) to update the column

```
if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'active')) {
            $table->integer('active')->default(0)->change();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not add but I'm using laravel 4.2.

Answer (score -3):

Create new migration file. and use `change()`

```
if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'active')) {
            $table->integer('active')->default(0)->change();
        }
    });
}
```

And also  be sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency to your composer.json file

Comment: `refresh` will not change the default value of anything, you're just resetting everything,