# Laravel: migrations change default value(boolean) of column

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

This is my current code.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('render', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('displayed')->default(1);
    });
}`
```

How to change the default value to 0 as below?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('render', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('displayed')->default(0);
    });
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: how to change the default value to default(0);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migrations change default value of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003469/laravel-migrations-change-default-value-of-column)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('render', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('displayed')->default(0)->change();
    });
}
```

Added `->change()`. Please see [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns)

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->boolean('is_active')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

is_active column is defined as a nullable boolean column using the boolean data type and the unsigned modifier. This will allow you to use the true and false keywords in your database queries instead of 0 and 1.